# TYPO3 t3events and readable URLs

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, realurl

I use the TYPO3 extension t3events. The docs are not up to date with the current version of Typo3.

I know I have to add some code of routeEnhancers in sites config.yaml. But don't know what and how.

How can I realize readable URLs for t3events within TYPO3 version 9 LTS and above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right with the routeEnhancers in site config.

If you need help implementing https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86365-RoutingEnhancersAndAspects.html it might be easiest if you write down the different type of URLs you get.

I don't know t3events but I am sure somebody can help then.